# swiping a row in table and delete it flutter

Tags: flutter

i hava a dataTable what i want to do is when i swip a row to the left it shows an icon on the right and when i click on it i can delete it .like the image .
this is my code :
i add it  on the function onSelectChanged:                                   SwipeActionCell() but it doesn't work any solution please !
[image]

```
  Expanded(
                          child: SizedBox(
                        child: SingleChildScrollView(
                          child: DataTable(
                              showCheckboxColumn: false,
                              columnSpacing: unitWidthValue * 0.021,
                              columns: [
                                DataColumn(
                                    label: Center(
                                  child: Text('number',
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: unitWidthValue *
                                              tableHeaderTextSizePercent,
                                          fontFamily: " SF Pro Display",
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w300)),
                                )),
                                DataColumn(
                                    label: Center(
                                  child: Text('name',
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: unitWidthValue *
                                              tableHeaderTextSizePercent,
                                          fontFamily: " SF Pro Display",
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w300)),
                                )),
                                DataColumn(
                                    label: Center(
                                  child: Text('date ',
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: unitWidthValue *
                                              tableHeaderTextSizePercent,
                                          fontFamily: " SF Pro Display",
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w300)),
                                )),
                                const DataColumn(label: Text('')),
                              ],
                              rows: widget.persons
                                  .map((person) => DataRow(
                                        cells: <DataCell>[
                                          DataCell(Text(person.number)),
                                          DataCell(SizedBox(
                                            width: unitWidthValue * 0.35,
                                            child: Text(person.sampleNumber,
                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                    fontSize:
                                                        unitWidthValue * 0.035,
                                                    fontFamily:
                                                        "SF Pro Display")),
                                          )),
                                          DataCell(Text(person.name,
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                  fontSize:
                                                      unitWidthValue * 0.035,
                                                  fontFamily:
                                                      "SF Pro Display"))),
                                          DataCell(Padding(
                                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                                top: unitHeightValue * 0.02),
                                            child: Column(
                                              children: [
                                                if (person.status ==
                                                        personStatus
                                                            .recorded ||
                                                    person.status ==
                                                        personStatus.associate)
                                                  const Icon(
                                                    Icons.save,
                                                    color: Color(0xFF0061B0),
                                                  )
                                                else if (person.status ==
                                                    personStatus.transmitted)
                                                  const Icon(
                                                    Icons.check_circle,
                                                    color: Color(0xFF34C759),
                                                  )
                                                else
                                                  const Icon(
                                                    Icons.warning,
                                                    color: Color(0xFFFF9500),
                                                  )
                                              ],
                                            ),
                                          ))
                                        ],
                                        onSelectChanged: (bool? isDispalyData) {
                                          setState(() {
                                            
                                            Navigator.of(context).push(
                                              PageRouteBuilder(
                                                pageBuilder: (context,
                                                        animation1,
                                                        animation2) =>
                                                    DisplayData(person,
                                                        isDisplayData: true),
                                                transitionDuration:
                                                    Duration.zero,
                                                reverseTransitionDuration:
                                                    Duration.zero,
                                              ),
                                            );
                                          });
                                        },
                                      ))
                                  .toList()),
                        ),
                      ))
                    ],
                  ),
                )
```

Comment: Use this package https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_slidable

Answer (score -2):

You can consult: Slidable.builder().

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).